# When my app is closed Strings are returning null in a class extending BroadcastReceiver when references static methods in another class

Tags: java, android, static, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am creating an app that has an sms sending feature. I am currently having an issue that involves the an AlarmManager (which is functioning properly) that calls a class that extends BroadcastReceiver. The class using the AlarmManager is MainMenu.class and the class extending BroadcastReceiver is AlarmReceiver.class.

Inside the MainMenu class the user enters the phone number and the message. In the AlarmReceiver class, I am attempting to send the sms by accessing a getPhoneNumber() method and a getMessage() method. When I do this and the app is closed the phone number and message both return null to the AlarmReceiver class even though it is accessing static methods in the MainMenu class.

Here is the code for the AlarmManager in MainMenu.class:

```
int hours, minutes;

hours = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
minutes = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);

Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(MainMenu.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
intentAlarm.putExtra("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
intentAlarm.putExtra("message", message);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),  PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainMenu.this, 1, intentAlarm,
                                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
```

Here is the code for the code for the AlarmReceiver class:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent();
        String phoneNumber = intentAlarm.getStringExtra("phoneNumber");
        String message = intentAlarm.getStringExtra("message");
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber,  null, message, null, null);
    }//end onReceive

}//end AlarmReceiver
```

I have even gone as far as trying to use SharedPreferences to remember the phone number and message but that still return a null also.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Android can kill your process at any time. Any in-memory variables you have at that time (including your phone number and message) will be lost.

We'd need to see the rest of your code to be sure, but saving the data to a SharedPreferences object can be a solution.

Comment: @Marius I understand this, but not every time I try to do this. The whole point of me using this AlarmManager is so I can fight against that so that I can keep the process going in the background when the app is closed so that an sms can be sent on a timer without the app being open still.

Comment: The AlarmManager is not intended to keep apps in the background. It is used to set an alarm that triggers in the future, even when the app is not running. If you want to keep an app running, you can use something like a background Service; or even a foreground notification in the notification bar. However, even that is not a guarantee. Android can still kill your app at any time it deems it necessary.

For your purposes, it's not necessary to keep the app in the background; simply persist your data to a SharedPreferences or some other persistent store, and load it in your BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have even gone as far as trying to use SharedPreferences to remember
>   the phone number and message but that still return a null also

No need to use `SharedPreferences` or `static` way to access variables from `MainMenu` class.

You can pass required data using Intent from `MainMenu` to `AlarmReceiver`:

```
Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(MainMenu.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
intentAlarm.putExtra("phone_number",MainMenu.getPhoneNumber());
```

Now get phone number from `intent` which is second parameter in `onReceive` method of AlarmReceiver class using `phone_number` key.

Comment: I had tried this before but I tried to use the intent that was used to call the BroadcastReceiver. Either way I tried using a completely separate intent to use putExtra() to pass the strings and they still turn out null in the AlarmReceiver class.

Comment: @saboehnke: what problem you are getting when passing data with `intentAlarm` Intent? and also try to use `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` flag instead of `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

Comment: I get the same error as I do when I use a different intent. I get that I am using an invalid destination address and invalid message. I tested to find that they are both returning null.

Comment: @saboehnke: why you are using different intent?

Comment: @saboehnke: if possible then update code with which you have tried send data using intent

Comment: Also changing that in the PendingIntent did not change anything. I updated the code as you requested.

Comment: @saboehnke: hmm, use `String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra("phoneNumber");
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");` instead of `i`

Comment: That also returned a null.

Comment: @saboehnke: use `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` instead of `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

Comment: I am using that. I just forgot to update the code on the post. Still returns null.

Comment: @saboehnke: are you kidding man i am saying use  second parameter of onReceive method which is `intent` to call `getStringExtra`. then why you are creating new intent inside `onReceive`

Comment: @saboehnke: just use `@Overridepublic void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra("phoneNumber");String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber,  null, message, null, null);}` code

Comment: Omg....I didn't realize I was creating a new intent there...really didn't mean to do that. I'm sorry about that. I appreciate the help.